# Is it possible that marginal and joint probability distributions are different in shape?

Tags: modeling, random-variable, joint-distribution, marginal-distribution

Suppose that $f$ is a joint probability distribution. Is it possible that some of the marginal distributions of $f$ has a different shape than $f$? For example, if $f$ is multivariate uniform or normal, are the marginal distributions then necessarily also uniform or normal?

The situation I have at hand is that there is great controversy regarding whether a particular marginal distribution is powerlaw distributed or not. However, none of the studies looked at the whole picture (there are 2 important variables) at once. I was wondering whether I could record data from the joint distribution, and solve the issue.

I only have a minor in statistics, so please explain any difficult parts also in a simple way. Thanks in advance!

Comment: The marginal and joint have different number of *dimensions*. How are you going to compare their shape in general? Do you mean instead to compare marginal with conditional?

Comment: Sorry, I just realized how my question does not make sense in all parts. The second sentence of the question is what I am after.

Comment: Like, suppose the joint distribution is bivariate normal. Can the marginal distributions ever be uniform?

Comment: No, the margins of a bivariate normal are normal.  But they can be different normal distributions.  In general you can take any two univariate distributions you please and construct a multitude of joint distributions for which those are the marginals.  As to your question: if you know the joint distribution, then you have the marginals.  It's unclear, though, whether you are asking a theoretical question about distributions or a question about data.

Comment: Whether the margins of multivariate bloorgh distribution always belong to a family called univariate bloorgh would be just a question about naming conventions, so I don't see how the normal case would be an example of anything.